# Is there a way to turn on and off Color Filter on MacOS Ventura from the CLI

Tags: macos, terminal, display

Setting -> Accessibility -> Display -> Color Filters ->

- Filter Type -> Grayscale
- Color Filters -> On

I'm try to do this from the terminal. Anyone know of some way to do this in MacOS Ventura?

Comment: Can you explain the workflow a bit more: why you need a Terminal command? Is this part of some larger script? Is the trigger automatic, based on criteria?

Answer (score 1):

The Shortcuts.app has an action to turn the Color Filter on or off; or to toggle it.

[image]

You can trigger shortcuts from the Terminal using the `shortcuts` command. You would need to make sure that the filter was already configured to use Greyscale.